# Cut-off cactus piece not showing signs of new roots, should I plant it in the ground anyway?

Tags: planting, cactus, transplanting

around 3 weeks ago I've cut off the top of my healthy moon cactus with the hopes of successfully replanting it. I followed some online tutorials and left it out on a plate to dry, kept it out of any direct sunlight and watered it only once or twice with just a drop of water so that it doesn't dry off completely. Currently it looks like this:
[image]
[image]
[image]

There are no signs of any roots and in most tutorials that I have found they had some signs of roots growing after a couple of weeks. Am I doing something wrong? Also, should I maybe put the plant on the ground even if there are no roots currently and hope the roots start to grow? If so, how much should I water it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can put it into a pot and water just slightly. Have the soil completely dry between waterings. 
It will develop roots in the soil when it’s ready :)

Comment: This works for Opuntia (prickly pear) - but those spread like that in the wild. Bits fall off, root on their own, etc.

Comment: Aha, thank you :D

Comment: Also should it be exposed to direct sunlight, indirect sunlight or almost no sunlight

Comment: Indirect sunlight would be good, I think!